# AJAX not calling the required C# controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

So I've been stuck on this one for some time and am fairly new to using AJAX, the issue I am having is with the below AJAX when I set a break point on the C# method it is supposed to call it is never reached and no errors are displayed.

The function `getCheckBoxes` is being called and executed as I stepped through what is happening with FireBug.

The second part will be the C# method I am attempting to execute with the AJAX, I got rid of the code inside as it is not even reaching it so it cannot be the problem. It is contained in `TestScriptResultsController`. I have tried with both `POST` and `GET` types. Any help would be appreciated.

```
getCheckBoxes = function getCheckBoxes () {
    //var firstDate = '@Model.FirstDate';
    //var lastDate = '@Model.LastDate';
    var fDateChanged = $("#FirstDate").datepicker('getDate');
    var lDateChanged = $("#LastDate").datepicker('getDate');
    var platformConfig = '@Model.PlatformConfigSelected';
    var triggered = '@Model.TriggeredSelected';

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("BranchCheckBoxes", "TestScriptResults")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { fDateChanged: firstDate, lDateChanged: lastDate, platformConfig: platformConfig, triggered: triggered },
        success: function (data) { $('#checkBoxes').html(data); }
    });
}
```

The controller action :

```
    public ActionResult BranchCheckBoxes(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate, string platformConfig, string triggered)
    {

        return PartialView(trs);
    }
```

Comment: Have you configured a route with those parameters?

Comment: what is the HTTP response from the AJAX call?

Comment: can u add error method in your $.ajax ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937185/asp-mvc-5-how-to-read-object-from-request-with-the-help-of-json-net , also check one more time how variable names, sometimes the problem with them but you don't see this.

Comment: [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 211ms] I believe is what you are wanting Jason. Just found this in FireBug as I am new to it also looking into this error now.

Comment: I was looking around a bit more and found the actual html response and this is must likely the problem. Thanks for pointing me in this direction Jason looking into it now.           >The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'firstDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult BranchCheckBoxes(System.DateTime, System.DateTime, System.String, System.String)' in 'DuckCallWeb.Controllers.TestScriptResultsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jason pointing me to the HTTP response lead me to the answer for this as .datepick('getDate') was returning an object instead of a string and therefore breaking before it could enter the ActionResult method I had setup. I changed the way I was retrieving the value from the datepicker, my data line in the AJAX call and I changed my actionResult parameters and it is now working. Is there a way I can give Jason some points on this I'm new to StackOverflow and his comment was very helpful in getting to the answer?

JavaScript for datePicker:

```
            $(function () {
            $("#FirstDate").datepicker()
              .on("input change", function (e) {
                  var firstDateChanged = $(this).val();
                  firstDateChange();

              });

        });
```

AJAX change:

```
data: { firstDate: firstDateChanged, lastDate: lastDateChanged, platformConfig: platformConfig, triggered: triggered },
```

Controller Change:

```
        public ActionResult BranchCheckBoxes(string firstDate, string lastDate, string platformConfig, string triggered)
    { }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your JavaScript object initializer syntax is backward for `data`. Try using:
   `data: { firstDate: fDateChanged, lastDate: lDateChanged, platformConfig: platformConfig, triggered: triggered }` The proper syntax is `{ 'key': 'value' }`
2. `'@Url.Action("BranchCheckBoxes", "TestScriptResults")'` will not work unless you are inside a Razor page. Ensure that your JavaScript is within a .cshtml or .vbhtml page or (preferably) use `url: '/TestScriptResults/BranchCheckBoxes/'`
3. `BranchCheckBoxes()` needs to have an `[HttpPost]` attribute, as MVC defaults to GET for controller actions:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult BranchCheckBoxes (...)
   ```

Comment: I tried all three of these suggestions same result it is never reaching my ActionResult method. For the second point it is contained within a .cshtml so I did not switch the format there but I can see with FireBug that it switches it to what you suggested  url: '/TestScriptResults/BranchCheckBoxes/'. Thanks for the responses all looking into the other comments now.